# "present continuous" form - have vs having

Tags: grammar, tense

German doesn't differentiate between present tense and present continuous tense as English language does. For instance,

```
Ich esse Brot
```

means, "I eat/am eating bread".

The same applies to the verb "habe".

```
Wir haben Essen
```

This can mean, "We have/are having food".

However, in English, one generally* uses

```
We are having food - meaning I am consuming the food
```

or

```
We have food - Just literal meaning of 'have'
```

So, if someone says

```
Wir haben Essen
```

How does German differentiate whether the person is "consuming" or just "possessing"?

[*] Some readers can disagree and say, "One can even use the present continuous even for possession". But the common interpretation if someone says "having food", means, "consuming".

Comment: By context. That sounds like a poor substitute for explicit inflection, and in some respects it is, but languages differ in what they express obligatorily and what they don't. (And this isn't the most extreme case. Mandarin expresses *tense* non-obligatorily! How do they know whether someone is talking about the past or the future? By context.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> We are having food.

can be expressed as:

> Wir essen gerade.
>
> Wir sind gerade am Essen.
>
> Wir sind gerade dabei zu essen.
>
> Wir sind zu Tisch / am Tisch.
>
> Wir haben gerade Frühstück / Lunch / Mittag / Abendbrot.

whereas

> We have food

translates to

> Wir haben Essen.
>
> Wir haben etwas zu essen.

expressing the possession.

Comment: It should be noted that "Wir sind am/beim Essen" expresses progressive aspect without "gerade" or similar. Actually, it becomes accepted that "am Essen" is a true, grammaticalized progressive aspect of German.

Comment: Yes, it is not standard written German.

Comment: According to Duden Online, "am" is supposed to be colloquial, which is just becoming wrong very fast. "beim" is accepted, at least there is no such limitation mentioned.

Answer (score 8):

`Essen haben` can only mean `to possess food`. If somebody is hav*ing* food, the verb `essen` must be used. Same goes for drinks (`Drink`, `Getränk` and `trinken`).

Comment: That is correct. However "trinken" requires a workaround when used in the way you described. While you can say "Wir haben Essen" the equivalent for drinks would have to be "Wir haben etwas zu trinken" since "Essen" can both be a noun and a verb while "trinken" is solely a verb.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the continuous form in German is expressed using respective signal words, like

> gerade, im Moment, momentan, augenblicklich, zurzeit, etc.

I can't currently think of an example there *I/We am/are having* translates to *Ich/Wir habe/n*.

> I am having a drink => Ich trinke (gerade) etwas
>   We are having food => Wir essen (gerade)

The only pattern that comes to my mind is

> I am having/I have problems with... => Ich habe gerade/Ich habe (für gewöhnlich) Probleme mit...
>   I am having/I have fun... => Ich habe gerade/Ich habe (für gewöhnlich) Spaß ...

but in neither of the examples I can think of the use of the simple form would indicate possession German. It's merely the difference between something happening right now or something happening usually.